# Custom PHP files wont load (Outside of magento 2 installation ubuntu + nginx)

Tags: ubuntu, magento, nginx, magento2

I am trying to let a custom script which is in the root directory of the Magento 2 installation but when I navigate to it on my browser, it returns a 404 error. For testing I tried to create an empty php file (abc.php) then navigate to it in the browser (domain/abc.php) it will still return a 404 even though I am certain the file exists in the location. I have tried CHMODding to 777 and changing ownership of the file to the same as the rest of the directory but I still get this 404.

I am using ubuntu 18.04 + NGINX as web server to run Magento 2. The Magento 2 installation is working on the browser, just any custom script I navigate to returns a 404. Has anyone ever had anything similar or have an idea on what to do next to debug this problem :/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've setup NGINX according to Magento 2 recommendations, then it will only allow PHP execution from a list of well defined, known PHP files. Namely, if you [look here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/nginx.conf.sample#L164), you'll take notice of:

```
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
    ...
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    ...
}
```

And [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/nginx.conf.sample#L201):

```
location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```

Which essentially means to deny execution for any PHP file other than `/index.php`, `/get.php`, etc.

So to allow for execution of a custom PHP file, you will need to adjust REGEX in the first location, to include the name of the custom file, e.g.:

```
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check|test)\.php$ {
```

The above would allow execution of `/test.php` in addition to other known PHP entrypoints.

Furthermore, if your Magento website's root in NGINX configuration is `/path/to/pub` (again, as per recommendations), then you need to place your custom file within that `pub` subdirectory, and not inside actual root of Magento.

Comment: Thanks Danila! It was nog the NGINX config but the HTACCESS file which was relocating the file to a 404

Comment: @MichaelGuimaraes .htaccess files belong to Apache, but you said you were using nginx. So either you're not using nginx at all or...?